# EF DbContext per web request + Custom RoleProvider = RoleProvider per web request or singleton?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, singleton, asp.net-roles, simple-injector

Using EF `DbContext` wrapped in interface(s), dependency injected per web request, to make sure the entire request deals with the same context. Also have a custom `RoleProvider` which consumes the `DbContext` by interface to customize authorization services.

Until now I have been using service locator pattern to resolve the `DbContext` instance in the custom `RoleProvider`'s no-arg constructor. This has caused some minor issues because the `RoleProvider` is singletonish, so it may hold onto a `DbContext` indefinitely whereas other requests may want to dispose of it during `Application_EndRequest`.

I now have a solution [based on this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4209580/304832), though using a different ioc container than windsor. I can use DI to new up a custom `RoleProvider` instance for each http request.

**My question is, should I?**

Having an open `DbContext` hanging off the `RoleProvider` seems wasteful. On the other hand, I know every MVC `AuthorizeAttribute` hits the `RoleProvider` (if it has a non-null `Roles` property, which most of ours do) so I suppose it could be useful to already have a `DbContext` in waiting.

The alternative would be to inject a different `DbContext` for the `RoleProvider` that is not per web request. This way the `DbContext`s that live only for the web request can be disposed at the end, without affecting the singletony `RoleProvider`.

Is either approach better, and why?

**Update after comments**

Steven, this is essentially what I did. The only difference is that I don't take a dependency on `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver`. Instead, I basically have the same exact thing in my own project, just named differently:

```
public interface IInjectDependencies
{
    object GetService(Type serviceType);
    IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType);
}

public class DependencyInjector
{
    public static void SetInjector(IInjectDependencies injector)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public static IInjectDependencies Current
    {
        get
        {
           // ...
        }
    }
}
```

These classes are part of the project's core API, and are in a different project than MVC. This way, that other project (along with the domain project) don't need to take a dependency on `System.Web.Mvc` in order to compile against its `DependencyResolver`.

Given that framework, swapping out Unity with SimpleInjector has been painless so far. Here is what the multipurpose singleton RoleProvider setup looks like:

```
public class InjectedRoleProvider : RoleProvider
{
    private static IInjectDependencies Injector 
        { get { return DependencyInjector.Current; } }

    private static RoleProvider Provider 
        { get { return Injector.GetService<RoleProvider>(); } }

    private static T WithProvider<T>(Func<RoleProvider, T> f)
    {
        return f(Provider);
    }

    private static void WithProvider(Action<RoleProvider> f)
    {
        f(Provider);
    }

    public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string username)
    {
        return WithProvider(p => p.GetRolesForUser(username));
    }

    // rest of RoleProvider overrides invoke WithProvider(lambda)
}
```

Web.config:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="InjectedRoleProvider">
    <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="InjectedRoleProvider" type="MyApp.InjectedRoleProvider" />
    </providers>
</roleManager>
```

IoC Container:

```
Container.RegisterPerWebRequest<RoleProvider, CustomRoleProvider>();
```

As for CUD, there is only 1 method implemented in my `CustomRoleProvider`:

```
public override string[] GetRolesForUser(string userName)
```

This is the only method used by MVC's `AuthorizeAttribute` (and `IPrincipal.IsInRole`), and from all other methods, I simply

```
throw new NotSupportedException("Only GetRolesForUser is implemented.");
```

Since there are no role CUD ops on the provider, I am not worried about transactions.

Comment: Can you implement your own `RoleService` and not use the `RoleProvider`? The `RoleProvider` is not very IOC friendly.

Comment: @Dismissile I'm trying to keep things as simple as possible. I wouldn't know where to start as far as plugging the RoleService into `IPrincipal.IsInRole(string)`. It wasn't difficult to wrap it and control its lifetime using the link in my question. What I want to know now is, which lifetime should I use.

Comment: Are you doing Windows Authentication or Forms Authentication? Are you using the built in ASP.net Membership database? If you're using either Windows or the standard Membership database then it's probably not as easy. If you're storing users/roles in your own database schema then it's probably not much harder than querying that table for a specific user to see which roles they are in.

Comment: @Dismissile it's FormsAuthentication. I do use the standard MembershipProvider, only the RoleProvider is custom. Basically I just store user passwords in the SqlMembershipProvider, and use it for authentication. All auhorization rules & data, however, come from custom tables in the app db (not the same db as SqlProviders).

Comment: You can build your own `SimpleInjectorRoleProvider`, which look quite much like that of Windsor. But... Wouldn't it be better you use a general `DependencyResolverRoleProvider` that uses the static `System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolver.Current` property. This way your provider is oblivious of the used container and it allows you to swap containers later on. There is only one catch though; the `IDependencyResolver` interface does not have a `Release` method, which makes it probably unsuited to be used with Windsor (although it will work fine with Simple Injector, StructureMap, Unity, and Autofac).

Comment: Another question: Should you inject an web request-scoped `DbContext` into your custom role provider? Doing this will mean that the `RoleProvider` operations run in the same transaction as the rest of the request. You need to think about this before hand, because you need to know whether an CUD operation should explicitly commit the `DbContext` or not. If it should run in its own little scope, perhaps it is better to inject an `IDbContextFactory` into your custom role provider.

Comment: Instead of defining your own `IInjectDependencies`, you can also use the `System.IServiceProvider` interface, which has the same semantics as the `IDependencyResolver.GetService` method. It is part of .NET so reusable to anyone. The Simple Injector `Container` class implements `IServiceProvider`, so it can directly be passed to your `SetInjector(IServiceProvider)` method.

Comment: One note about the `IServiceProvider`. It is a good interface, but almost all Common Service Locator adapters [implement it incorrectly](http://commonservicelocator.codeplex.com/discussions/44293#post564134) and are useles as `IServiceProvider` implementations. Please be aware of that.

Comment: @Steven, I also noticed `IServiceProvider` doesn't define a default method for returning multiply-registered services, like `IDependencyResolver` does. I may keep `IInjectDependencies` just to define `IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)`, and extend `IServiceProvider` for the other `GetService` method.

Comment: You can do `(IEnumerable)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IEnumerable<Thing>))` to get a collection of things with the service locator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the [Griffin.MvcContrib](http://blog.gauffin.org/2011/09/a-more-structured-membershipprovider/) project. It contains a `MembershipProvider` and `RoleProvider` implementation that make use of the MVC `DependencyResolver`.

You can configure the `RoleProvider` like this:

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="MvcRoleManager">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MvcRoleManager" 
      type="Griffin.MvcContrib.Providers.Roles.RoleProvider, Griffin.MvcContrib"
    />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

It makes use of the System.Web.MVC `DependencyResolver` class so you need to configure an `IDependencyResolver` implementation for the DI container you are using. With Simple Injector (and the [SimpleInjector.MVC3 integration NuGet package](https://nuget.org/packages/SimpleInjector.MVC3)), you need the following configuration in your `Application_Start` event:

```
container.RegisterAsMvcDependencyResolver();
```

The `Griffin.MvcContrib.Providers.Roles.RoleProvider` takes a dependency on a `IRoleRepository` which is defined in the same assembly. Instead of having to implement a complete role provider you can now just implement the `IRoleRepository` and register it in your container:

```
container.Register<IRoleRepository, MyOwnRoleRepository>();
```

You can find this project [here](https://nuget.org/packages?q=griffin.mvccontrib) on NuGet.

**UPDATE**

And now let's answer the question:

The Griffin.MvcContrib RoleProvider will be singleton, and the question now moves to the `IRoleRepository` and its dependencies, but the question indeed still remains.

If all you do is read from the Role Provider (never update the database); in that case it doesn't matter which lifetime you choose, as long as you don't reuse the same `DbContext` over threads.

However, when you do use the role provider to update the database, things get different. In that case I would give it its own context, and let it explicitly commit it after each operation. Because if you don't, who is going to commit those changes? When running in the context of a Command Handler (and especially a [TransactionCommandHandlerDecorator](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=91)), the operation will be committed after the command succeeded and rolled back when the command failed. Perhaps it is fine to roll that change back when the command failed. But when the role provider runs outside the context of a command handler, who is going to commit it? I'm sure you will be able to solve this, but I believe you end up with a system that is hard to grasp and it will dazzle other developers who try to find out why those changes didn't commit.

Comment: +1 for the info, I will look into this project. But the question still remains: Is it better to keep the RoleProvider singletony, or to have it recreated for each http context? Maybe it doesn't even matter..?

Comment: "If all you do is read from the Role Provider (never update the database); in that case it doesn't matter which lifetime you choose..." Really? Say I register `DbContext` to be per web request, and then dispose of it during `Application_EndRequest`. If `RoleProvider` is singleton, and it uses the per-web-request `DbContext`, it will throw an exception during the second and all subsequent requests, because the DbContext was disposed of after the first request.

Comment: Well of course, that would violate one of the first rules of DI: A service should not depend on a service which lifetime is shorter than its own lifetime. The role provider is always a singleton, since it is configured in the configuration file. In that case you should use a abstract factory or a service locator (what the `DependencyResolver` is) to request the dependencies on each method call. This way you ensure you don't use a stale dependency. But still, what lifetime that `DbContext` dependency has, doesn't matter much (as long as you won't reuse the same context over threads).