# Issue unit testing an asp.net MVC controller that inherits from a custom base controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing

So i'm using Moq and starting to write unit tests for my controller actions.

All of my controllers inherit from a base CustomController class that provides a userId property set in the constructor to be the value of Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.  This way I can pass the userId to my service layer simply by passing contactId.

This does not seem to work well with this unit test:

```
  var serviceMock = new Mock<IFormService>();
        serviceMock.Setup(g => g.GetForm(2)).Returns(new FormViewModel() {ID = 2, Name = "Mock Form"});
        var controller = new FormController(serviceMock.Object);
        var result = controller.Index(2);
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "View Result is null");
```

It throws an exception on the base CustomController where it tries to set the userId from Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey.

"UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\App_Data' is denied."

Has anyone else come across this issue or have any thoughts on a way around it?

Comment: It may help to see your constructor, but my guess is you will need to inject a mock membership provider, and configure your DI container to use a lifecyle based on the request. Basically if it is a dependency it needs to be in the contructor so you can control its behaviors in a test. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193484/how-do-i-control-membershipprovider-instance-creation-lifetime

Answer (score 0):

You maybe forget to set the membership provider in your webconfig:

```
<system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="20">
</system.web>
```